# Minitest-Capybara: find "a" - click "a" - unable to find link or button

Tags: capybara-webkit

Is it possible that if I write in my integration test:

```
all("a")[0]
```

the test goes well but when writing:

```
click_on(all("a")[0])
```

I get the error message "unable to find link or button"?

The  has

```
href="javascript:void(0)"
```

Answer (score 0):

The element return by all("a")[0] have a .click function.

```
all("a")[0].click
```

Or instead find by the name

```
all("#name_of_link").click
```